# How to properly extract data that returns None in Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to improve an existing snippet that extracts data from: https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1b6f00c8cd99e0daac5718c743ef9a51af40f95feae23bf29960ae1f66a1cff7 and I cant figure out how to extract some fields as it returns None.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1b6f00c8cd99e0daac5718c743ef9a51af40f95feae23bf29960ae1f66a1cff7', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')

val = soup.find('span', class_='u-label u-label--value u-label--secondary text-dark rounded mr-1').text
transfee = soup.find('span', id='ContentPlaceHolder1_spanTxFee').text
fromaddr = soup.find('span', id='spanFromAdd').text
token = soup.find('span', class_='hash-tag text-truncate hash-tag-custom-from tooltip-address').text

print ("From: \t\t ", fromaddr)
print ("Value: \t\t ", val)
print ("Transaction Fee: ", transfee)
print ("Tokens: ")

main_data=soup.find_all("ul", class_="list-unstyled mb-0")
for i in main_data:
    print ("%s" % i.find_all("a")[-1].get_text() + " %s" % "https://bscscan.com/token/"+i.find_all("a")[-1]['href'])
```

Current Output:

```
From:             0x6bdfe0696aa4f81245325c7931c117f15459e07a
Value:            0.679753633258727619 BNB
Transaction Fee:  0.00059691 BNB  ($0.18) 
Tokens:           
   Binance: WBNB Token https://bscscan.com/token//address/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
   FaraCrystal (FARA)  https://bscscan.com/token//token/0xf4ed363144981d3a65f42e7d0dc54ff9eef559a1
```

Wanted Improvement: #- additional data below the Tokens(numeric values)

```
From:         0x6bdfe0696aa4f81245325c7931c117f15459e07a
Value:        0.679753633258727619 BNB
Transaction Fee:  0.00059691 BNB  ($0.18) 
Tokens: 
    0.679753633258727619 ($200.28)  Binance: WBNB Token   https://bscscan.com/token//address/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
   95.834051318695064337 ($198.62)  FaraCrystal (FARA)    https://bscscan.com/token//token/0xf4ed363144981d3a65f42e7d0dc54ff9eef559a1
```

Comment: It is not problem with None but you simply didn't write code to get these values. You get all `<a>` - `i.find_all("a")` - but this value `0.679753633258727619 ($200.28)` is **NOT** in `<a>` but in `<span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not problem with `None` but you simply didn't write code to get these values.

You get all `<a>` - `i.find_all("a")` - but `0.679753633258727619 ($200.28)` is in `<span>`.

You could use better method to get rows because your version mix values from two different places and later it is problem to get correct values.

```
main_data = soup.select("ul#wrapperContent div.media-body")
```

And you create wrong urls - with `/token//address/` and `/token//token/` but both should have only `/token/` - because you use wrong method to get `main_data`

I also use better formating - `{:>35} | {:18}`

```
print("Tokens:")

main_data = soup.select("ul#wrapperContent div.media-body")

for item in main_data:
    all_span = item.find_all("span")
    last_span = all_span[-1]
    
    all_a = item.find_all("a")
    last_a = all_a[-1]
    
    print("{:>35} | {:18} | https://bscscan.com{}".format(last_span.text, last_a.get_text(strip=True), last_a['href']))
```

Result:

```
Tokens:
     0.679753633258727619 ($200.65) | Wrapped BNB (WBNB) | https://bscscan.com/token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
    95.834051318695064337 ($196.37) | FaraCrystal (FARA) | https://bscscan.com/token/0xf4ed363144981d3a65f42e7d0dc54ff9eef559a1
```

---

Full working code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


url = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1b6f00c8cd99e0daac5718c743ef9a51af40f95feae23bf29960ae1f66a1cff7'
#url = 'https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc54d83b870a1b4159f12bff092c8a24dfa045e133b07d3a3a41898293ac86c71'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

req = Request(url, headers=headers)
html = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

val = soup.find('span', class_='u-label u-label--value u-label--secondary text-dark rounded mr-1').text
transfee = soup.find('span', id='ContentPlaceHolder1_spanTxFee').text
fromaddr = soup.find('span', id='spanFromAdd').text
token = soup.find('span', class_='hash-tag text-truncate hash-tag-custom-from tooltip-address').text

print("From:            ", fromaddr)
print("Value:           ", val)
print("Transaction Fee: ", transfee)
print("Tokens:")

main_data = soup.select("ul#wrapperContent div.media-body")

for item in main_data:
    all_span = item.find_all("span", class_='mr-1')
    #for number, span in enumerate(all_span):
    #    print(number, span.get_text(strip=True))
    last_span = all_span[-1]
    
    all_a = item.find_all("a")
    last_a = all_a[-1]
    
    print("{:>35} | {:18} | https://bscscan.com{}".format(last_span.get_text(strip=True), last_a.get_text(strip=True), last_a['href']))
```

Comment: Its does not display the correct data when I try using this url: https://bscscan.com/tx/0xc54d83b870a1b4159f12bff092c8a24dfa045e133b07d3a3a41898293ac86c71

Comment: it needs to add `class` in line `all_span = item.find_all("span", class_='mr-1')`

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use `select_one`  method to select css selector in loop so values can be extract

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

req = Request('https://bscscan.com/tx/0x1b6f00c8cd99e0daac5718c743ef9a51af40f95feae23bf29960ae1f66a1cff7', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')

main_data=soup.select("div.row > div.col-md-9 >ul.list-unstyled.mb-0")[1]
for i in main_data:
    print(i.find_all("a")[-1].get_text())
    print("https://bscscan.com/token/"+i.find_all("a")[-1]['href'])
    print(i.select_one("span.mr-1 > span").get_text())
```

Output:

```
Wrapped BNB (WBNB)
https://bscscan.com/token//token/0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
0.679753633258727619 ($200.83)
FaraCrystal (FARA) 
https://bscscan.com/token//token/0xf4ed363144981d3a65f42e7d0dc54ff9eef559a1
95.834051318695064337 ($198.34)
```

OR For prices: in which data is inside span tag so you can use `select` method with css selector

```
price=main_data.select("span.mr-1 > span")
for p in price:
    print(p.get_text())
```

Output:

```
0.679753633258727619 ($200.83)
95.834051318695064337 ($198.34)
```